# Spark ML(using PySpark): Errors while using Multilayer Perceptron Classifier

Tags: apache-spark, neural-network, pyspark, classification, apache-spark-ml

I'm working on a binary classification problem using different classifiers available on Spark-ML; was able to successfully train and evaluate the models(such as Naive Bayes, Random Forest, Logistic Reg etc.), however, I'm running into issues while working on Multilayer Perceptron Classifier using the same training and test data.

May be SO could help me figure out where am I going wrong!

```
# spark version
sc.version
>>u'2.3.0.2.6.5.25-1'

# python version
import sys
print (sys.version)
>>2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) 
 [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)]

# Training data
print type(training_allData),training_allData.count(),len(training_allData.columns) 
>><class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> 392836 97 

# Test data
print type(test_allData),test_allData.count(),len(test_allData.columns)
>><class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> 88862 97 

# no. of features in my training data after one-hot encoding
len(training_allData.columns)-1
>>96
```

I use the below code as described in the Spark ML web page:-
(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier)

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier

inputneurons = len(training_allData.columns)-1
layers=[inputneurons,(inputneurons+2)/2,2]
trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers, blockSize=128, seed=1234)
# train the model
model = trainer.fit(training_allData)
# predict the model
result = model.transform(test_allData)
```

And, it throws 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error:-

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2243.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 339.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 339.0 (TID 9185, executor 6): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Layer.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Layer.scala:664)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Layer.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Layer.scala:660)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1092)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:809)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1162)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGS$.runLBFGS(LBFGS.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.LBFGS.optimize(LBFGS.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardTrainer.train(Layer.scala:854)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.train(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.train(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Layer.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Layer.scala:664)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Layer.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.DataStacker$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Layer.scala:660)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1092)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:809)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
```

However, the code seems to be working fine for different input layer sizes(< 94) and I was able to train and score the model on test data. A 'result' data frame is created, but cannot access the underlying data.

```
print result.count(),len(result.columns)
>>88862  100

type(result)
>><class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

result.printSchema()
>>root
  |-- input_label: long (nullable = true)
  |-- feature_1: double (nullable = true)
  |-- feature_2: long (nullable = true)
  |-- feature_3: long (nullable = true)
  |-- feature_4: double (nullable = true)
  |...
  |...
  |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
  |-- label: double (nullable = false)
  |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
  |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
  |-- prediction: double (nullable = false)

result.select("label","prediction","probability").show(10)
```

Error:-

```
An error occurred while calling o1809.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 325.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 325.0 (TID 8700, executor 18): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => vector)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: A & B Dimension mismatch!
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.BreezeUtil$.dgemm(BreezeUtil.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.AffineLayerModel.eval(Layer.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.forward(Layer.scala:508)
at org.apache.spark.ml.ann.FeedForwardModel.predictRaw(Layer.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:343)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.predictRaw(MultilayerPerceptronClassifier.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$anonfun$1.apply(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassificationModel$$anonfun$1.apply(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:116)
... 19 more
```

*P.S: I am relatively new to NN, so I researched several SO posts and tried their solutions as well, but none seems to be working in my case!*

Comment: Just wanted to understand, did you not use the Vector Assembler before pushing it to fit() ? Is it not a good idea to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the first layer with the exact number of features, I'd say that you have more neurons in the first layer than input features. Please check the number of features you pass in `inputneurons`.